# Document not getting deleted in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm using Vuex form my state management in my web app. I wanted to delete a document from my firestore database but when I click the button nothing happens.

This is segement of the card header with a delete icon so when clicked it deletes the document:

```
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header card-head-color">
        <span class="card-header-text"
          >{{ stock.name }} <small>(Price: {{ stock.price }})</small></span
        >
        <i
          class="fa fa-trash-alt float-right trash-icon"
          aria-hidden="true"
          @click="deleteStock(stock.key)"
        ></i>
      </div>
```

The delete stock mutation is as follows:

```
DELETE_STOCK(id) {
    db.collection("stocks")
      .doc(id)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document Deleted!");
      });
  },
```

The delete stock action is:

```
  deleteStock: ({ commit }, id) => {
    commit("DELETE_STOCK", id);
  },
```

This is where the delete stock action is called in the template inside methods:

```
   deleteStock(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch("deleteStock", id);
    },
```

But whenever I click the Icon nothing happens.

Comment: Mutations just manipulate the vuex. Firestore stuff needs to be in action section. Synchronous issue that Raffobaffo mentioned is the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are using an async function inside your mutations in vuex, but the [vuex documentation clearly states](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous):

> Mutations Must Be Synchronous

To fix this problem, you should do the async call to db inside your action

```
  deleteStock: ({ commit }, id) => {
       db.collection("stocks")
         .doc(id)
         .delete()
         .then(() => {
            console.log("Document Deleted!");
            //now you can commit and remove it from the state
            commit("DELETE_STOCK", id);
           });
  },
```

Comment: But I have setup an action for the mutation

Comment: The action does the async stuff, and then commits the mutation.

Comment: @Raffobaffo make your answer better by providing more written explanations and one simple sample so I can vote u up. U r on the right track

Comment: @KickButtowski Did it. Thanks for the head up

Comment: @Raffobaffo does not deleteStock needs to async await in it? since it is asyncrouns ?

Comment: my bad you used the thenables k looks awesome, and error section would be awsome

Comment: It still dies not work and what should i put in the mutation

Comment: I think @Raffobaffo answers is more than enough to give a clue for you to do some searching. You can do this bro just do it .

Comment: @Saaransh Menon I mention in my comment what to do , so read it carefully you can do this

Comment: @KickButtowski I got the delete function working but my component shows the old state along with the old state after deleting...is there a way to clear the old state and add the new state.